# How do qualified dividends get a lower tax rate than ordinary dividends?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, dividends

IRS Form 1040 instructions say that "qualified dividends" have a lower tax rate than ordinary.  Yet they are included in the ordinary and added to everything else for the ordinary rates.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Line 3b includes all dividends, so the [instructions for Form 1040](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi), Line 3a (qualified dividends) say to,

> Use the Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet or the
> Schedule D Tax Worksheet, whichever applies, to figure your tax. See
> the instructions for line 16 for details.

It's similar for Line 7 (capital gain/loss) as well. The total amount of gains/loss shows up on Line 7, but the tax worksheets determine what falls under long-term vs. short-term rates.